# Does a RC glider always loop when launched?

Tags: aircraft-design, flight-controls, glider, model-aircraft

In the below video, the guy sets "launch mode" for hand launch where he adds a little bit of elevator.

Will a glider always loop up when launched horizontally, even if the tail is set to produce zero lift?

And what determines whether the glider will loop up or loop down (and crash, if possible) during launch?

Comment: Do you see how the Spoilerons change the CP of the wing? (Launch/CruiseThermals)

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni No

Comment: Most of what you're seeing here is nearly unique to discus style hand launches. There are also javelin-style launches (which are rather different) and hi-start launches (different again) and winch launches (yup, different still). Oh, and although they're unusual in RC models, a few people do towed launches (which are completely different).

Comment: And there is also scale (Reynolds) too.  One can see we want a thin wing with little camber, *adding more camber as we slow down*.  Oh, yes, airliners do this too.

Comment: It's just being launched way above its trim speed, so it pitches up to regain trim speed and doesn't slow down back to its trim speed until it's completed a loop.  If you set the elevator to a position that trims to the launch speed, it would go straight.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni: That's over-simplifying quite a bit. This is designed for F3K. For (say) the 2 hour thermal flight required for LSF Level V would call for a *rather* different design.

Comment: Well, Jerry, if I could shrink down to say 100 grams I would do fine in that discus glider. While I start from simple (where else), I would be interested in exploring *differences* for various applications.

Comment: @John K that is correct, but we need to develop the speed envelope.  It works much better if static "stability" is minimized.  A launch at 50 mph "flat" at the horizon should rise a little.  I might "trim" to 35 mph.  We must remember the effect of vertical motion (rise from excess lift) on the the relative wind *as well as the tail and wing torques*.  This may be where CG placement comes in.

Comment: @JohnK **Its just being launched way above its trim speed** That mean that wings produce much more lift then weight of glider?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unrelated to AIRCRAFT and belongs on Drones.SE.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni I have also big problem with roll,if slightly breeze is out there,plane bank and crash after 2 meters...

Comment: Ha, so many memories of that too.  Much good information on RCGroups website.  In a nutshell, solve issues aerodynamicly *around CG*.  "Moving weight" is a poorly understood crutch that leads to other problems.  Be like Space X, keep building and testing at the hill.  A hint is to look at that good old paper airplane.

Comment: @RalphJ we could migrate to drones SE

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't loop when launched correctly.

If you launch it so fast that lift is greater than weight, if will pitch up, and may either stall (as happened to me with my foam plane) or may enter a phugoid cycle where it climbs, dives, climbs again, and so on.

But if you launch it at the right speed and right angle (usually slightly down) it will fly smoothly to a gentle touchdown far away. This is the"trim speed" John K was talking about.

By angle I mean direction of flight, not pitch angle, or angle of attack. A stable glider will correct these as a rule.

But if your launch leaves too little lift, it will pitch down. This usually results in an immediate crash, due to the small altitude budget available.

The more lift your elevator is trimmed to create, the higher the optimum speed will be
But it must always have lower angle of attack than the wing, or the plane **will be unstable or will nosedive and crash**

I often threw my plane at the ground as hard as I could, just to watch it nearly crash, and then zoom up to twice my height.

Comment: **The more lift your elevator is trimmed to create, the higher the optimum speed will be**  If CG is in front of wing 1/4 chord line,then elevator must procude downforce(negative lift). If CG is behind 1/4 chord line then elevator must produce lift.. to keep forces in balance...Isnt it?

Comment: @EBV821 correct. But the CG does not *directly* set the trim. It merely sets how much force is required from the elevator. You still need to trim for speed. S slower airspeed at a given altitude will need the plane to fly more nose high, and vice versa. The forces will remain the same, despite the different trim settings.